# Using screen fragments on android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on android app and am trying to get fragments working but I've run into a problem.

When the app launches it loads an activity which is supposed to house the two fragments. Fragment1 contains a list of stored logins and fragment 2 will show the details associated with that login.

The list fragment is supposed to retrieve data from the SQLite database and display on the screen and once the item is clicked, it loads the second fragment, but I am having problem getting the first stage working.

In my main activity class I have the following.

```
public class PasswordListMain extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.password_management);
    }

}
```

The password_management XML file contains the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/passwordList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.BoardiesITSolutions.PasswordManager.PasswordListFrag">
    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

It just contains the fragment as this is the portrait screen, I thought I'd get this bit working before getting it working side by side.

The PasswordListFrag contains the following

```
public class PasswordListFrag extends ListFragment{

    Common common; 
    com.BoardiesITSolutions.logic.ManagePasswordList managePasswordList;

    ArrayList<String> savedPassword;
    TextView txtNoRecords;
    ListView myListView;
    ArrayAdapter<Spanned> passwordArrayAdapter;
    AdView adView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflator, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.password_list, container, false);

        myListView = getListView();
        common = new Common(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        //AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
        common.requestAdvert(adView);

        managePasswordList = new ManagePasswordList(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        //txtNoRecords = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.password_noRecords);
        populateListArray();

        common.showToastMessage("Adapter updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        //myListView.setOnItemClickListener(mListView);

        return view;
    }

    private void populateListArray()
    {

        ArrayList<Spanned> passwords = managePasswordList.getPasswordList();
        if (passwords != null && passwords.size() > 0)
        {
            passwordArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Spanned>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, passwords);
            setListAdapter(passwordArrayAdapter);
            passwordArrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
            myListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            txtNoRecords.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else
        {
            txtNoRecords.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the XML for the list fragment

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/password_noRecords"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="There are currently\nno saved logins"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>
    <ListView 
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView">
    </ListView>
        <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adUnitId="5555555"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        </com.google.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

When the app loads it instantly crashes when it tries to load this screen.

The error is

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo`
`PasswordListMain: android.view.InflatException: Binary XML file line`
`#7 Error inflating class fragment`

I have no idea what's causing this or how to fix the problem.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I'm assuming that the class path is incorrect in the fragment element for your xml declaration.

Comment: I've double checked but it appears to be OK.

Comment: ListFragments require that a Listview have the id  "@android:id/list", is that the case?

Comment: Yea it does, I've added the XML file, sorry I thought I did, but it does have the ``@android:id/list``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess for the issue is this line (but admittedly I'm unsure):

```
myListView = getListView();
```

You're calling it before the fragment has a view - and I don't think that will work too well.  I would recommend doing your initialization work of the views involved in `onActivityCreated()` instead of in `onCreateView()` and the other components (like your data store thing and `Common`) in `onCreate()`

Comment: Yes, this is a good answer, onCreateView() should only be used to create the view, do your work in onActivityCreated()

Comment: Thanks you were write, did this and seems to be working, just got to get the second fragment working now :)